# How to write regex to find empty space after colon in string with no new line in text format?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

> I am creating one regex to find words after colon in my `pdftotext`. i
>   am getting data like:
>   I am using this xpdf to convert uploaded pdf by user into text format.

```
$text1 = (new Pdf('C:\xpdf-tools-win-4.00\bin64\pdftotext.exe'))
                ->setPdf('path')
                ->setOptions(['layout', 'layout'])
                ->text();
                $string = $text1;
                $regex = '/(?<=: ).+/';
                preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
```

In `->setPdf('path')` path will be path of uploaded file.
    **I am getting below data :**

```
Full Name:                               XYZ

Nationality:                             Indian

Date of Birth:                           1/1/1988

Permanent Residence Address:
```

In my Above data you can see residence address is empty.
Im writing one regex to find words after colon.

but on $matches it results only:
Current O/P:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz
            [1] => Indian
            [2] => 1/1/1988
        )

)
```

It skips if regex find whitespace or empty value after colon:
I want result with empty value too in array.
Expected O/P:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => xyz
                [1] => Indian
                [2] => 1/1/1988
                [3] => 
            )

    )
```

Comment: share your code base

Comment: What is the separator character(s) between each key-value pair?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the actual input data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have edited my code with actual output and expected output with my current regex.

Comment: Can you also give the data as a PHP string?  My answer should work using what you posted, assuming there are line separators at the end of each line.

Comment: i dont have PHP string as i am converting my pdf to text format. i already show you what i am getting after uploading pdf file. and array too. in my layout i am not getting `\n`.  xpdf converts my pdf to text as it is with help of `>setOptions(['layout', 'layout'])`.  so i dont have any seperator for new line etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The OP has changed his question after several answers were given. 
This is an answer to the original question.

Here is one solution, using `preg_match_all`.  We can try matching on the following pattern:

```
(?<=:)[ ]*(\S*(?:[ ]+\S+)*)
```

This matches any amount of spaces, following a colon, the whitespace then followed by any number of words.  We access the first index of the output array from `preg_match_all`, because we only want what was captured in the first capture group.

```
$input = "name: xyz\naddress: db,123,eng.\nage:\ngender: male\nother: hello world goodbye";
preg_match_all ("/(?<=:)[ ]*(\S*(?:[ ]+\S+)*)$/m", $input, $array);
print_r($array[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => xyz
    [1] => db,123,eng.
    [2] => 
    [3] => male
    [4] => hello world goodbye
)
```

Using capture groups is a good way to go here, because the captured group, in theory, should appear in the output array, even if there is no captured term.

Comment: its working thanks bro. but i dont have \n in my code. if i remove \n from your code its not working

Comment: @amitsutar I edited my answer to cover the possibility that you might have whitespace in your values.

Comment: its not working for my current scenario. i dont have \n in my string.

Comment: @amitsutar Then your question makes no sense.  There has to be some separator character(s) between each key/value pair.

Comment: i am converting my pdf into text format with xpdf. after that i am getting this kind of data. so how wil i get \n in my data.

Answer (score 2):

Your code, $regex = '/\b: \s*'\K[\w-]+/i';, ended right before \K. You have 3 quotes, and the first 2 quotes capture the pattern.

Anyways, what you can do is use groups to capture the output after the colon, including whitespace:

```
$regex = "^.+: (\s?.*)" should work.
```

Comment: It works. You just need to select the group captured by the parentheses and print it out.